# How to save (Database) bool using Shared Preferences - Flutter(Dart)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, boolean

I want to save a bool value (The value is already made in my Firebase Realtime Database whith a default value of false), but when I save the value it doesn't save. I follow the videos I use their code examples (modified to work for my code ofc) but it still doesn't save...(The name of the Database is `People` and the value I want to change is called `Joined` so I'm referencing the database when I say People['Joined'])

```
//Reference Database
  Query dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('People');
  DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('People');
```

```
//This is just a block with all the database's info
Widget listItem({
    required Map People,
  }) {
    //shared Preferences start
      savebool() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool("People['Joined']", true);
    }
    //shared prefs end
    return Slidable(
      startActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const BehindMotion(),
        extentRatio: 1 / 5,
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icons.add,
            label: 'Join',
            onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
              setState(() {
                //change value from false to true
                People['Joined'] = true;
              });
              //now i save it
              savebool();
              //but when I refresh it didn't save//
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),...}
```

What I've tried:
I tried adding the `getbool` and `super.initsate` but I'm still struggling to add that code into my code, because it keeps brining up errors. If you know how to add the code in the context of my code, help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
I added the following code and I think I am getting somewhere but it still doesn't work

```
//above the onpressed
savebool() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool("People['Joined']", People['Joined']);
      print(People['Joined']);
    }

//onpressed:
onPressed: (BuildContext context) async {
              setState(() {
                People['Joined'] = true;

                savebool();
                print('saved');
              });


//IN MY MAIN.DART
late SharedPreferences prefs;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        prefs = value;
      });
      //load data
      _loadData();
    });
  }

  _loadData() async {
    bool joined = prefs.getBool("People['Joined']") ?? false;
    print('loadData :$joined');
    //this returns TRUE when i restart the app
  }
```

**What I think the problem is:**
The value is returning true when I restart the app so it must be working, so the value is being saved but it doesn't work...I have written in my code `People['Joined'] ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,` so when it is true it will be green. But when i restart app it remembers that it is true but the color returns to blue. BECAUSE I am saving a variable called joined (see code) so it is saving that value and not `People['Joined']`...So how do i fix this?

Comment: "it keeps brining up errors" What errors? Please edit your question to show the exact error message and stack trace that you get. --- Also: you're still not making any read/write operations to Firebase, so I'm not sure what behavior you're expecting there. Are you asking [how to write a value to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#write_data)?

Comment: No the errors are not important because I know I'm writing it wrong, I can't write the getbool and setbool above the code because I can't reference the database from that area of the code so I do it on another place which makes it harder to do this...What I'm asking: I have a bool in my database and in my app I change it from false to true... but the value doesn't save so what I'm asking is "how do I save the bool when I change it?". I do apologize for any confusion or not enough info @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: "I can't reference the database from that area of the code" Why not? What happens if you call `reference.set(yourValueHere)` in the `onPressed`?

Comment: it gives the error `undefined variable`

Comment: Did you replace the `yourValueHere` in the code I gave with the name of the variable you actually want to save?

Comment: Yes I did , I changed it to `People['Joined']`

Comment: I chagned a lot of the code let me edit my original question maybe you can then understand beter

Comment: I still don't see any call to actually save the value to the database in that update. Something like `reference.set(People['Joined'])` or whatever it is that takes the value you have and writes it to Firebase.

Comment: when i change it the way i do it doesn't affect the database, which is actually what I want

Comment: When I change the bool form false to true it changes everything to true how can I make each individual one true?